# x86 assembly memory operands

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-registers, operands

Hello all
I have a question relating to x86. In the Intel manual some instruction might take different types of memory operands.
eg. IDIV r/m8 or IDIV r/m16 or IDIV r/m32 or IDIV r/m64
now they are all IDIV is there a possibility to know if the operand is m8, m16,m32 or m64?
I was thinking if operand is m8 then it is addressed by an 8 bit register eg. ax if 32 then eax,esp...
Is my assumption correct? Correct me if I'm wrong
Any suggestions welcome
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the register that is used as an operand resolves the ambiguity. (Note, however, that `ax` is a 16-bit register, not an 8-bit register -- that would be `ah` or `al` for the high or low byte, respectively.)

If you're only referring to memory operands, you need to use a `BYTE PTR`, `WORD PTR` or `DWORD PTR` specifier to resolve the ambiguity, like this:

```
mov dword ptr [eax], 0
```

This example sets the 32-bit quantity ("double word") at the address contained in `eax` to 0.

Comment: thanks Martin. I just compiled a simple C code and got movl -8(%ebp), %eax cmpl -4(%ebp), %eax –
is the "l" in the movl and cmpl the indicator you are talking about were l=long=32bit?
if yes do you know the indicator for the byte, 2-byte and double word is?
thanks

Comment: Anshuman has already answered this -- the difference is that AT&T syntax encodes the operand type in the instruction mnemonic (`movb`, `movw` or `movl`), whereas Intel syntax doesn't (`mov`). This is why Intel syntax sometimes requires a specifier such as `dword ptr` to resolve the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

1. Whether the operand is m8, m16 or m32, the register used to address the memory location can be 16 or 32 bits.  (Or in 64-bit mode, 64 or 32-bit).  Almost always, you want pointers of the same width as the mode, unlike with data.
2. To specify how many bits are to be read from memory, you need to use one of the size specifiers `byte`, `word` or `dword` before the address. For example in NASM syntax:

`idiv byte [bx] ; m8`

`idiv word [bx] ; m16`

`idiv dword [bx] ; m32`

Comment: thanks Anshuman. I just compiled a simple C code and got movl -8(%ebp), %eax cmpl -4(%ebp), %eax –
is the "l" in the movl and cmpl the indicator you are talking about were l=long=32bit?
if yes do you know the indicator for the byte, 2-byte and double word is?
thanks

Comment: Yes - byte is b, word is w, and long (double word) is l. This is the AT&T syntax for mnemonics. (I had used the Intel syntax in my examples)

Comment: okey so if I am using a dissambler to generate the assembly, would the generated assembly be Intel or AT&T syntax? or is it also dependent on the dissambler I use?

Comment: Most disassemblers can be configured to produce one particular syntax. With gdb's `disassemble` you can use `set disassembly-flavor att` or `set disassembly-flavor intel`.

Comment: You can't use 8-bit registers in addressing modes.  (And you usually don't want to use registers narrower than the current mode, i.e. only use 32-bit addresses in 32-bit mode, but you *can* use 16-bit address size.)  In any given mode, only 2 different address sizes are possible.  In most modes, 16 or 32, but in 64-bit mode only 64 or 32.